# What windows form object should i use for the output for my C# 2D game? eg picturebox, base form or other

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d, picturebox

I am making a simple 2d game similar to zelda in c# for practice and to get some insight into C#, and just because i want to try a bunch of different things.

I have enough of the game running to actually play, but i was wondering if i was doing everything in the cleanest manner possible.

Currently i only have a picturebox in my form and display the contents of the game which refreshes on a clock with an interval of 20ms.

What I am wondering is if a picture box is the best way of displaying my content or if there is something cleaner, or better to be using instead?

I havent had any problems but i dont know what other options are available and i dont want any default form buttons in my project as i would prefer to create them myself.

If i can get any extra advice for making a simple 2d game that would be great, been making it almost exclusively offline without any tuts just on what i know from the courses i did last year so it has been a very insightful journey!

Comment: I would use a Panel, but with no particular justification.

Comment: Is there any difference or reason for that? i was just watching a tutorial where the guy was using a panel, just wondered what the difference is, he also showed he used threading instead of a clock for his graphics which looked alot cleaner